# Template class with variable number of members in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

This is more of a curiosity with C++ templates than something useful. It supposed to be a class with a variable number of members. Is it likely that this will be compiled down to direct member access?

```
// type equality
template <typename X, typename Y> struct Eq { static const bool out = false; };
template <typename X> struct Eq<X, X> { static const bool out = true; };

template <typename First, typename... Rest>
class Table {
    First _field;
    Table<Rest...> _nextTable;
public:
    template <typename T>
    T &get() {
        if (Eq<First, T>::out)
            return (T&)_field;

        return (T&)_nextTable.get<T>();
    }
};

template<typename First>
class Table<First> {
    First _field;
public:
    template <typename T>
    T &get() {
        return _field;
    }
};

int main() {
    Table<int, double> table;
    table.get<double>() = 11.1;
}
```

Comment: Can't you just check the assembly? Google godbolt compiler explorer, and punch the code in there.

Comment: It looks to me like you are basically reimplementing [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

Comment: With optimizations on, most likely yes.

Comment: Yeah it seem I am reimplementing std::tuple. I just checked with godbolt and it seems that with -o3, all the calls optimized out.

Comment: @BendegúzNagy Well yours is a poor mans tuple :). It wont work as expected with duplicate types and also there is no EBCO (which can be forgiven if its just written for fun)

Comment: @Arunmu It was written for fun. The former can be solved by passing the index of the given type to access, defaulting to zero as the first of that type in the table.

Answer (score 2):

```
return (T&)_nextTable.template get<T>();
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name

Comment: Thanks for helping out on StackOverflow.. Including the relevant part of the documentation would help, and make your answer more valuable.